# How to convert image from a url to text using pytesseract without saving in memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a URL that contains an image, which has only text in it. I want to extract the text present in the image. I was able to find a solution using pytesseract. However, I need to save the image in local memory & then use it in the function to get the text. Is there any way to do this in-memory?

```
img_resp = requests.get(img_url)
with open('test.png','wb') as img:
    img.write(img_resp.content)
print(image_to_string(Image.open('test.png')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass response content to `Image.open` like this:

```
import io
import requests
from PIL import Image

img_resp = requests.get(img_url)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_resp.content))
```